# Merging multiple oracle queries to produce one result

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Is it possible to execute the following query as one query?

[code]

```
select count(*) from tableA;
select count(*) from tableB;
select count(*) from tableC;
select count(*) from tableD;
```

[/code]

ie. the result to be something like this

```
|TablA|TableB|TableC|TableD|
|50   |300   |30    |9|
```

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
select * from
(select count(*) from tableA),
(select count(*) from tableB),
(select count(*) from tableC),
(select count(*) from tableD);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes

```
select count(*) from tableA;
union all
select count(*) from tableB;
union all
select count(*) from tableC;
union all
select count(*) from tableD;
```

Answer (score 0):

Following should work with any DBMS.

```
SELECT *
FROM   (select count(*) as tableA from tableA) a
       full outer join (select count(*) as tableB from tableB) b
       full outer join (select count(*) as tableC from tableC) c
       full outer join (select count(*) as tableD from tableD) d
```

Comment: Thanks. This didnt work. It complained about a missing keyword on teh character 'd'

Answer (score 0):

try this:


with 
one as (select count(1) as counterA, 1 as dummy from tableA),
two as (select count(1) as counterB, 1 as dummy from tableB),
three as (select count(1) as counterC, 1 as dummy from tableC),
four as (select count(1) as counterD, 1 as dummy from tableD)

select one.counterA, two.counterB, three.counterC, four.counterD from one, two, three, four where one.dummy = two.dummy and two.dummy = three.dummy and three.dummy = four.dummy;